# How to change the application when opening a folder on the desktop

Tags: gnome, nautilus, thunar, file-association

I want to change the default file explorer from nautilus to Thunar. I searched hours around the web and followed all the advices but nothing did work.
What my expected result is: When double-clicking on a folder on the desktop Thunar should open.

My system is VERSION="18.04.3 LTS (Bionic Beaver)"

What I've done so far:

- I changed all some files (so all files in which nautilus was set to open folder) in /usr/share/applications/ to use Thunar:

  > user@computer:/usr/share/applications$ grep -i Thunar * (and exclude the Thunar-Files itself)
  >   backup-mimeinfo.cache:inode/directory=org.gnome.baobab.desktop;nautilus-folder-handler.desktop;org.gnome.Nautilus.desktop;Thunar-folder-handler.desktop;
  >   defaults.list:inode/directory=Thunar-folder-handler.desktop
  >   defaults.list:x-directory/normal=Thunar-folder-handler.desktop
  >   mimeinfo.cache:inode/directory=org.gnome.baobab.desktop;nautilus-folder-handler.desktop;org.gnome.Nautilus.desktop;Thunar-folder-handler.desktop;
  >   nautilus-autorun-software.desktop:TryExec=thunar
  >   nautilus-autorun-software.desktop:Exec=thunar
  >   nautilus.desktop:Exec=thunar
  >   nautilus.desktop:Exec=thunar
  >   nautilus-folder-handler.desktop:Exec=thunar
  >   nautilus-home.desktop:Exec=thunar
  >   nautilus-home.desktop:Exec=thunar
  >   org.gnome.Nautilus.desktop:Exec=thunar
  >   org.gnome.Nautilus.desktop:Exec=thunar
  >   thunar-volman-settings.desktop:Exec=thunar-volman-settings
- I changed the Mime-Association

  > sudo xdg-mime default Thunar.desktop inode/directory application/x-gnome-saved-search
- I checked the mimeinfo.cache:

  > user@computer:/usr/share/applications$ grep inode mimeinfo.cache 
  >   inode/directory=org.gnome.baobab.desktop;nautilus-folder-handler.desktop;org.gnome.Nautilus.desktop;Thunar-folder-handler.desktop;
- I changed mimeapps.list in my home-directory:

  > user@computer:~/.config$ cat mimeapps.list
  >   [Added Associations]
  >   application/x-nautilus-link=Thunar-folder-handler.desktop;
  >   inode/directory=Thunar-folder-handler.desktop;
  >   [Default Applications]
  >   inode/directory=Thunar-folder-handler.desktop
  >   application/x-gnome-saved-search=Thunar-folder-handler.desktop

But it's still not working. So in principle my only question: How does ubuntu decides what to to when double-clicking on a folder placed on the desktop?

Comment: You might have some settings to configure default applications from a GUI, depending on what desktop environment you're using. If you're on KDE Plasma, then there should be an application called "Default Applications."

Comment: You need to set thunar as the file manager that handles the desktop. Currently, it is still nautilus that handles the desktop.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, thanks to the hint of user vanadium I found out that thunar can not handle the desktop:
[Question at stackexchange.com](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/73047/having-desktop-icons-with-thunar-on-arch-linux-with-openbox)

So I have to deal with it...